# Programmatically get the location set up in regional settings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am having some trouble getting the location setting of the PC. I realize it's easy to get the culture settings but I am talking about the home location setting as per the following dialog. I am using [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) but [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) is fine too.

[image: this is what i mean]

Comment: Use Shell API to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegionInfo` class like this:

```
String currentRegion= System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Did you try this? This isn't the region OP is looking for. IIRC the "Home Location" is independent from this.

Comment: You didn't mention that you were on Windows 8.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 and it works for me. What is IIRC?

Comment: So when you change the "Home Location" as described above, this value changes too? I have found that this isn't the case. IIRC = If I remember correctly.

Comment: That does not return the contents of the dropdown that i have shown in my question. If i change the dropdown and query the RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName it remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, I hacked this out of the powershell cmdlet [`Get-WinHomeLocation`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852157.aspx):

If you declare the following class:

```
public static class GeoTools
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetUserGeoID(int GeoClass);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetGeoInfo(int Location, 
                                        uint GeoType, 
                                        StringBuilder GeoData, 
                                        int Length, 
                                        ushort LangID);
}
```

then you can:

```
uint GEO_FRIENDLYNAME = 8u;
var homeLocationGeoId=GeoTools.GetUserGeoID(16);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
int geoInfo = GeoTools.GetGeoInfo(homeLocationGeoId, 
                                  GEO_FRIENDLYNAME, 
                                  stringBuilder, 
                                  256, 
                                  0);
var homeLocation = stringBuilder.ToString(); //yay!
```